# How can I give each dynamic button created their own event

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm creating a Windows form application for the students at my local college, and for some time I've been stuck on a single problem. The project that I'm working on allows users to add friends or send friend request, I've created a UI displaying the user's details (First Name and Last Name *Required for Registration) that send user A a friend request. I'm creating the UI through a loop based on the number of records of a table in a database where the logged in user's ID key is in the second column. The problem I'm getting is when I try and allow the user to accept the friend request from a button created along with the panel for the details for the request. As of now I have 3 panels that have been created and all of them contain 3 names, I'm trying to get the name for each label that holds the user's details as mentioned above based on the button that was clicked from each panel, but if I click on the first panel's button, I only get the last panel's label's text displayed. Any help would be appreciated

The code I have for creating the panels

```
            {
                
                Panel pnlFriend = new Panel();          
                int y = pnlFriend.Location.Y;
                pnlFriend.Width = 315;
                pnlFriend.Height = 56;
                y = 55;
                pnlFriend.Location = new Point(3, y);               
                pnlFriend.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;

                Label lblfriendName = new Label();          
                lblfriendName.Location = new Point(3, 5);
                lblfriendName.Font = new Font("Arial", 10);
                lblfriendName.Text = names[nameCounter].ToString();

                Label pendingCap = new Label();
                pendingCap.Location = new Point(3, 28);
                pendingCap.Width = 123;
                pendingCap.Height = 13;
                pendingCap.Text = "has sent a friend request";

                Button accept = new Button();           
                accept.Width = 51;
                accept.Height = 23;
                accept.Location = new Point(157, 23);
                accept.Text = "Accept";
                accept.Click += new EventHandler(acceptFriendRequestService);

                Button decline = new Button();      
                decline.Width = 51;
                decline.Height = 23;
                decline.Location = new Point(214, 23);
                decline.Text = "Decline";
                decline.Click += new EventHandler(declineFriendRequestService);

                pnlFriend.Controls.Add(lblfriendName);
                pnlFriend.Controls.Add(pendingCap);
                pnlFriend.Controls.Add(accept);
                pnlFriend.Controls.Add(decline);
                flpFriendRequest.Controls.Add(pnlFriend);

                nameCounter++;          
            }
```

Comment: This sounds like you'd rather want a databound control like DataGridView - will allow you to have a Column of buttons bound to the individual records.

Comment: Not sure it's clear what the problem is.  We don't see what you are doing in those event handler methods, but you would typically examine the sender to see who the caller is.

Comment: @LarsTech care to elaborate please

Comment: You first.  It's not clear what the issue is.

Comment: @LarsTech okay so I'm creating components dynamically, they are all added into a panel, as a parent control, now each panel contains 2 buttons accept and decline. My issue is if I click on the first panel's button i get a label's text from the last panel only

Comment: `I'm creating components dynamically`  That we see.  It sounds like you care talking about the code in `acceptFriendRequestService`, which we don't see.

Comment: ``` public void acceptFriendRequestService(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
   MessageBox.Show(getFirstName(lblfriendName.Text));
  } this is the event

Comment: The description of the issue provided doesn't make things clear. It may be better to break it up. Provide short description, then show some code. Repeat as necessary. A random guess of what may be occurring is that the control's properties aren't being updated when you want them to. If that's the case, try adding a "Refresh" after the desired properties are set (after the text property is set) - lblfriendName.Refesh(). Without seeing additional code, it's difficult to know if what you're trying to accomplish could be done in a different manner.

Comment: OK, we're getting closer.  That method calls a `getFirstName` function.  What's going on in there?  `lblfriendName` must be referencing a label that was built with the designer, because your "dynamic" label that you created doesn't have a name.  You won't be able to reference it that way.

Comment: @LarsTech ```public string getFirstName(string s)
  {
   var result = Regex.Match(s, @"^([\w\-]+)");
   string output = result.ToString();
   return output;
  } theres the method

Comment: Maybe you are getting confused by `lblfriendName.Text` in your code, because that control is not the dynamically created control you have in that panel.  We don't see how you are setting the value of that label either.

Comment: @LarsTech that is the label that is dynamically created

Comment: The value is specified with ```names[nameCounter].ToString();```

Comment: `lblfriendName` is declared elsewhere. When you  do this `lblfriendName = new Label();`, you create a new instance of a Label. The last created is the instance that you use (you have just one `lblfriendName` Label). Build a UserControl.

Comment: @Jimi I changed that after I posted the question, probs should've mentioned that

Comment: The you need to update your code and post all the relevant parts that are in play here. Don't post code in comments, update your question. -- **Build a UserControl**.

Comment: Everythings updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Button `Tag` to save the data and then retrieve it later.

Example

```js
Button accept = new Button();
accept.Width = 51;
accept.Height = 23;
accept.Location = new Point(157, 23);
accept.Text = "Accept";
accept.Click += new EventHandler(acceptFriendRequestService);
accept.Tag = names[nameCounter].ToString();

void acceptFriendRequestService(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  var name = ((Button)sender).Tag;
  //Do your work here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use what is called a closure or capture of a variable in an inline function.

```cs
Button accept = new Button();
accept.Click += (sender, args) =>
{
    // you can access accept var here
};
```

If you create a bunch of buttons in a loop, make sure not to use a member variable or even a local variable that is outside your loop. You want to create a brand new button inside the loop so that the lambda can reference the correct variable.